# iOS 7: on textfield did change the firstresponder my application is crashing

Tags: objective-c, ios7, textfield

I have editable tableview cell,and when i move from first textfield to last textfield in the table it is crashing.Code is.The below code is for textfield delegate

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
   NSIndexPath *indexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:1];
    EditableTextFieldCell *cell = (EditableTextFieldCell *)[self.documentdetailTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];
    self.actField = cell.textFieldOne;
    if([self.actField canBecomeFirstResponder]){
        [self.actField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
 -(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if (self.actField == textField) {
      [self.actField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField*)sender
{
if (self.quantityValue !=nil)
        {
            [self.quantityArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[sender tag] withObject:sender.text];
            [[self.documentItemsArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]] setQUANTITY:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[sender.text doubleValue]]];
            [self.documentdetailTable reloadData];
        }
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
self.quantityValue=@"";
return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)theTextField
{
    NSLog( @"text changed: %@", theTextField.text);
    self.quantityTextField = theTextField;
    self.actField = theTextField;

}

//add the textfield listeners
[self.quantityTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
```

But it is crashing and I am getting message like:

```
**EditableTextFieldCell _didChangeToFirstResponder:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc3c6bf0**
```

Comment: That means the textfield which you are referring to is released at this point of time. Such errors are coming in iOS 7 if we release a subview just after adding it to a view.

Comment: remove this line [self.quantityTextField resignFirstResponder];

Comment: If i remove this line [self.quantityTextField resignFirstResponder];  then i cannot make other textfield as first responder

Comment: Is there any solution to fix this in iOS7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this answer somewhat is stupid but the correct answer.
I have checked for tableview cellforrowatindexpath and added an identifier

```
static NSString *EditableTextFieldCellIdentifier = @"EditableCell";

// using custom cells to show textfield and multiple columns
EditableTextFieldCell *cellText = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:EditableTextFieldCellIdentifier];
```

And this fixed my problem and also crash.

Comment: I am facing the same issue only with iOS7, its working in iOS 6. It is crashing only when we fast scrolling and then select any cell from the TableView.

Comment: Thanks for this! We have a custom table cell view with a text field. I had to add the reuse identifier to avoid crashes in iOS 7, when the user scrolls a text field row off the screen and selects another one. It works without the reuse identifier in iOS 8.

Answer (score 8):

We had the same issue and it was because we where using "old code" to create/dequeue the custom UITableViewCells...

What we had to do was to add this lines in the ViewDidLoad

```
[self.myTableView registerClass:[ExpenseListCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ExpenseListCell"];
[self.myTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ExpenseListCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ExpenseListCell"];
```

and then "clean" the function cellForRowAtIndexPath to just use the dequeue function:

```
ExpenseListCell *cell = (ExpenseListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I suspect that, since they included storyboards, the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier manages the creation of the cells, so you don't need anymore this lines that we where still using after the dequeue:

```
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ExpenseListCell" owner:cell options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

NOTA: We are not using storyboards

Changing this, solved our problem on iOS7.

Comment: Just a small detail: this change is not compatible with iOS5

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly. I had to change A LOT of code but it was worth it!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
I fixed it by placing identifier to the table view cell's nib file.
then a dequeue call at cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
static NSString *fsCellIdentifier = @"configurationCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:fsCellIdentifier];
```