# UITableView showing unexpected rows on iPad (ios7):

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

[image]

It had the first row and the third row that I don't want to show. I had found the same question but he(she) doesn't have the same problem with me, and I cannot solved the problem.With iPad(ios 6) it's work fine, but this bug happen on iPad(ios7).Here is my code:

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return (calEnabled.boolValue ? 2 : 1);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return 1;

    if (calEnabled.boolValue) {
        return (reminderEnabled.boolValue ? 2 : 1);
    }

    return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.row == 0) {
        return 44;
    }

    return 200;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tabView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CallSettingsTableViewCell* sourceCell = [tabView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VMSettingsTabCell_ID"];
    if (sourceCell == nil) {
        sourceCell = [[CallSettingsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"VMSettingsTableCell_ID"];
    }

if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    sourceCell.textLabel.text = calEnabled.title;
    sourceCell.accessoryView = calEnabled.ui_switch;
}
else if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    sourceCell.textLabel.text = reminderEnabled.title;
    sourceCell.accessoryView = reminderEnabled.ui_switch;
}
else
{
    [sourceCell disableRightSwipe];
    sourceCell.textLabel.text = calReminder.title;
    sourceCell.accessoryView = calReminder.ui_picker;
}

sourceCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
sourceCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

return sourceCell;
}
```

pleased help me to solve it. Thank in advance.

Comment: I would say it's the section header what you see there, not extra rows

Comment: you can `return 0.1f;` for the delegate methods: `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:
heightForFooterInSection:` and see if it makes a difference. I noticed in some situations that in iOS 7 there's sometimes a header and footer added, even if not provided.

Comment: so,if it as you said, how can I disable those headers?

Comment: Look this link If it can help you:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087867/ios-7-on-textfield-did-change-the-fristresponder-my-applicaiton-is-crashing/19398284#19398284][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087867/ios-7-on-textfield-did-change-the-fristresponder-my-applicaiton-is-crashing/19398284#19398284

Comment: return `0.1f` (note that `return 0;` doesn't seem to work) in the mentioned methods. There may be other solutions as well, but I haven't investigated this too much.

Comment: Is it grouped or plain tableview ?

Comment: @alex-i it's work fine, thanks so much. But I aslo saw two separate lines between 2 section.How can I disable one of those?

Comment: Why are you using 2 sections if in the end, all you want is having 2 cells ?

Comment: @KIDdAe I don't got what you mean, but the problem of this question is  as alex-i said before.I need 2 sections, and the second section show the picker view if the switch on it turn on.

Comment: Ok but currently your reminderCell is in your second section, that's why you have a space between those cells, they are not in the same section.
You can have those 2 cells in the first section and still display your picker in the second section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the code below to remove the space between sections, or you can simply try using  UITableViewStylePlain instead of UITableViewStyleGrouped.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.001;
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.001;
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)] autorelease];
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: This question had the right answer from @alex-i, but I also approved your answer because It's the same with alex-i's answer.and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tabView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        CallSettingsTableViewCell* sourceCell = [tabView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VMSettingsTabCell_ID"];
        if (sourceCell == nil) {
            sourceCell = [[CallSettingsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"VMSettingsTableCell_ID"];
        }

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        sourceCell.textLabel.text = calEnabled.title;
        sourceCell.accessoryView = calEnabled.ui_switch;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        sourceCell.textLabel.text = reminderEnabled.title;
        sourceCell.accessoryView = reminderEnabled.ui_switch;
    }
    else
    {
        [sourceCell disableRightSwipe];
        sourceCell.textLabel.text = calReminder.title;
        sourceCell.accessoryView = calReminder.ui_picker;
    }

    sourceCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    sourceCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return sourceCell;
    }
```

Comment: nope, it's work wrong, even it doesn't show my switch at the second row.

Comment: @Ketan Patel, if you're going to continue editing posts at your current rate, please make the edits more substantial.