# popToRootViewController crashes when tableView is still scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

When I give a good swipe to my tableView and press the "Back" button before the tableView ended it's scrolling, my app crashes. I've tried the following:

```
- (void) closeViewController
{
    [self killScroll];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)killScroll
{
    CGPoint offset = sellersTableView.contentOffset;
    [sellersTableView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
}
```

That didn't work, same crash. I don't see why, the error I'm getting is the following:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

So that means that the tableView is still requesting a cell when everything is already being deallocated. Makes no sense.
Then I tried this:

```
- (void) closeViewController
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    sellersTableView.dataSource = nil;
    sellersTableView.delegate = nil;
    sellersTableView = nil;
}
```

Gives me the same error. Any ideas?

**Update:**
My delegate methods

> creation

```
if (textField == addSellerTextField) {
        sellersTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(addSellerTextField.frame.origin.x + addSellerTextField.frame.size.width + 10, addSellerTextField.frame.origin.y - [self heightForTableView] + 35, 200, [self heightForTableView])];
        sellersTableView.delegate = self;
        sellersTableView.dataSource = self;
        sellersTableView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.05];
        sellersTableView.separatorColor = [[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.15];
        sellersTableView.rowHeight = 44;
        sellersTableView.layer.opacity = 0;
        [self.companyView addSubview:sellersTableView];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{sellersTableView.layer.opacity = 1;} completion:nil];
    }
```

> cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if (tableView == sellersTableView) {
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        if ([sellersArray count] > 0) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [sellersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        } else {
            UILabel *noSellersYetLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, sellersTableView.frame.size.width, [self heightForTableView])];
            noSellersYetLabel.text = @"no sellers yet";
            noSellersYetLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            noSellersYetLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            [cell addSubview:noSellersYetLabel];
            sellersTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        }
    }
```

> removing

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == addSellerTextField) {
        [self updateSellers:textField];
    }
}
- (void)updateSellers:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self hideSellersTableView];
}

- (void)hideSellersTableView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{sellersTableView.layer.opacity = 0;} completion:nil];
    sellersTableView.dataSource = nil;
    sellersTableView.delegate = nil;
    [sellersTableView removeFromSuperview];
    sellersTableView = nil;
}
```

Solution
So apparently putting the `dataSource = nil` and `delegate = nil` into `textFieldDidEndEditing` fixed the problem. Thanks everybody for the answers!

Comment: Can you provide some additional information on your viewController hierarchy?

Comment: check if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087867/ios-7-on-textfield-did-change-the-firstresponder-my-application-is-crashing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's strange behaviour of UITableView. The easiest way to resolve this issue just set the `dataSource` and `delegate` property of `UITAbleView` to nil before you make a call of function `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`. Furthermore you can use more common solution and add the code that set the properties to nil into the `-dealloc` method. In addition you no need the `-killScroll` method.

After a short research  I have realized what the problem is. This unusual behaviour appeared in iOS 7. The scroll view retained by its superview may send message to delegate after the delegate is released. It happens due to `-removeFromSuperview` implementation `UIScrollView` triggers `-setContentOffset:` and, eventually, send message to delegate.

Comment: I have tried setting `dataSource` and 'delegate` to nil before closing, but I still get the crash. Thx for the info btw :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add following lines at the beginning of `dealloc` method:

```
sellersTableView.delegate = nil;
sellersTableView.dataSource = nil;
```

No need to use hacks like your killScroll method.

Also, I can't see why you want to call both `popToRootViewController` and `dismissViewController`.
If you dismiss a view controller which is embedded in a navigation controller, navigation controller itself as well as all contained view controllers will be released.

In your case you'll have just weird animation.

Comment: Tried your approach, but it's still crashing with the same error. About my `popToRootViewController` & `dismissViewController`, you're absolutely right, that was stupid of me.

Comment: In this case, please provide code of your delegate and datasource methods.

Answer (score 1):

`setContentOffset` method won't help you, try to set

```
sellersTableView.dataSource = nil;
```

somewhere in your `viewWillDisappear` method.
This is not a good practice of course.

Comment: Tried this, but no luck. Still crashing with the same error. Thx though!

Answer (score 1):

Change you closeViewController like below and see if works

- (void) closeViewController

{

```
sellersTableView.dataSource = nil;
sellersTableView.delegate = nil;
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: Thx for your answer! Buuuuuut, tried it and same result.

Comment: What I am thinking is you didn't provided sellersTableView's connection to your xib/storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that setting the tableView (or it's delegate) to nil is the issue. You should be able to perform both dismissViewControllerAnimated or popToRootViewController individually without having to modify the tableView in this way.

So the issue is most likely due to calling both of these methods at the same time (and with animated = YES), and in doing so asking your viewController setup to do something unnatural.

Looks like upon tapping a "close" button you are both popping to a `rootViewController` of a `UINavigationController`, as well as dismissing a modal `viewController`.

In doing so, you're dismissing a modal `viewController` which is likely presented by the `topViewController` of the `navigationController` (so top vc is holding a reference to modal vc). AND you're trying to kill the top vc via the popToRootViewController method call. And you're doing both of these things using `animated = YES`, which means they take some time to complete, and you can't be sure when each finishes (ie you can't be sure when dealloc will be called).

Depending on your needs you could do one of several things.

Consider adding a delegate property to your modal vc. Dismiss the modal vc, and in the completionBlock of the modal vc tell its delegate that it's finished dismissing. At that point call popToRootViewController (because at this point you can be sure that the modal is gone and scrolling wasn't interrupted).

If it's your navController that's been presented modally, then do this in the opposite order. Notifying the delegate that the pop operation has completed, and do the modal dismissal then.

Comment: I removed the `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`, that was my mistake. But other than that, the error still comes and crashed my app. Thx for the answer though!